# Neither vs either in a negative statement

Tags: neither-nor, either-or

Is it correct to say:

- A: You can't say a word to anyone.
- B: Yes, but you can't say a word to anyone *either*.

or

- A: You can't say a word to anyone.
- B:You can't say a word to anyone *neither*.

*Neither* a person A, *nor* a person B can't say a word. Shouldn't it be *neither*?
(In the example I found it's *either*)

Comment: Could you please show your research?  Otherwise this an off-topic proofreading request.

Comment: The _can't_ is already negative, so you use _either_. _Neither_ is used for situations where the negative needs to be repeated because of conjunction: _He didn't say a word, and neither did I._

Comment: In certain dialects, you might say "you can't say a word to noone neither."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The negation is already present in "can't", so "either" is used.

A variation with "neither" would be:

- A: You can't say a word to anyone.
- B: Neither can you [say a word to anyone].

Answer (score 1):

The reason it is "either" is because your ending word is talking about the action, rather than a pair of people. Therefore, you should have "either" in that scenario. Additionally, I don't believe you're allowed to end a sentence with "neither", either. =)

Either: "You aren't allowed to A and you aren't allowed to B either."

Neither: "Neither person A nor person B are allowed to talk to anyone."

Extra source: [Either/Neither Examples](http://www.learnamericanenglishonline.com/Orange%20Level/O17%20Either%20and%20Neither.html)

Comment: (1) Why didn't you use NOR in the second sentence?
(2) In the second sentence as well shouldn't we use IS instead of ARE?

Comment: No, the second sentence should stay "are." Imagine replacing persons A and B with the word "they."

"They are allowed to talk to anyone."

Comment: @Adam You're right on the 'nor'. I was contemplating how to approach the example there and overlooked that. Thank you =).

Comment: According to GMAT rules I believe we should use IS. Here is the rule http://www.800score.com/content/guidec4view1V1d.html . Your thoughts on this please.